# How to enable ASP.NET Web API Help Page documenting in Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Areas to help organize my Web API. I essentially have 2 sets of APIs, one for performing account/user management and the other is using the service that I provide.

So my routing looks like this

"api/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{accountNumber}"

Before I started using Areas, the Help Page was working fine, but after I started using Areas it stopped generating the help documentation. Is there something I need to configure to get Areas to be included by the Help page?

Comment: Web API doesn't have the concept of 'Areas' like in MVC, so could you share more details as to how your controller looks like and how are you planning to use this '{area}' in Web API?

Comment: I keep seeing posts/articles mention that Web API doesn't have Areas, yet the code works. I can call any of the API urls and they route correctly. It's just the Help Page that doesn't see them. So what exactly do you mean that it doesn't have the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used multiple routes to solve the same thing without areas:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo",
                           "api/Foo/{fooId}",
                           new {controller = "Foo", fooId = RouteParameter.Optional});

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo_Bar",
                           "api/Foo/{FooId}/Bars/{barId}",
                           new {controller = "Bar", barId = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

Works fine with the HelpPage.

I've also tried [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net), but I prefer my routes.

Comment: ok, I did what you said and it's now working. The auto-generated code for adding an Area has an AreaRegistration class which maps the routes using context.MapRoute. Since I saw that I didn't think I needed to configure the routes in WebApiConfig. I guess that is what they mean by WebApi not exactly supporting Areas.

Comment: Could I simply just create subfolders in Controllers to organize all the controllers and just make sure I add all the routes? Any reason to keep going with Areas now that the help page is working?

Comment: Small issue, the controller portion of the URL listed in the help page uses upper case :( ex.  POST api/User/users/{id}

Comment: With my example you don't need areas.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I can't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to create subfolders/subnamespaces in Controllers. But it wouldn't affect the route paths.

Comment: With the routes in my example you don't need to see the controller name as a part of the relativt path. You can change Foo/{fooId} to abc/{fooId}, and it will still use FooController.